# How to wait for element.all to get resolved?

Tags: protractor

I am trying to find index of an item from a listing view. To find out the index I am using this function

```
    function restFunction(appName) {
     var indexForItem = 0;
     var a = element.all(by.repeater("app in itemList").column("app.itemName")).each(function (element, index) {
            element.getText().then(function (name) {
                console.log("Name is " + name);
                if (name == "sam") {
                    indexForItem = index + 1;
                    console.log("Ïndex is " + indexForItem );
                    a = index;
                }
            });
        });

        return a;
    }
```

In protractor how can I wait for the above promise to get resolved. Right now when I call my restFunction I always get promise in pending state

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks incorrect especially, the return value. You are returning the function call - `element.all(locator).each(eachFunction)` which will return a Promise which will not resolve to anything. Check the documentation [here](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.each).

> Returns
>
> > !webdriver.promise.Promise  A promise that will resolve when the
> >     function has been called on all the ElementFinders. The promise will
> >     resolve to null.

Though you are re-assigning the value later inside the call, since the mode is async, it doesn't wait till the re-assignment.

You have to change it to return the index directly

```
function restFunction(appName) {
    return element.all(by.repeater("app in itemList").column("app.itemName")).each(function (element, index) {
        return element.getText().then(function (name) {
            if (name === "sam") {
                return (index+1);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

And when you call the function - You have to resolve the Promise

```
restFunction('').then(function _resolvePromiseOfCall(value){
    console.log('value')
})
```